# stop repeat insertion of json parsed data in sqlite database using shared preferences

Tags: android, json, sqlite

Stop repeat insertion of json parsed data in sqlite database using shared preferences.
CatagoryActivity.java:- here i parsed json data and call method to add it in sqlite database.

```
public void get_data(String data) {

        try {
            JSONArray data_array = new JSONArray(data);

            for (int i = 0; i < data_array.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(data_array.get(i).toString());

                Message add = new Message();
                Log.d("JSONVALUE :", obj.toString());
                String category = obj.optString("category");
                String status = obj.optString("status");
                String imgLink = obj.optString("imagelink");
                String id = obj.optString("id");
                add.setCategory(category);
                add.setStatus(status);
                add.setImagelink(imgLink);
                add.setId(id);
                objlist.add(add);
                dataBaseHelper.addSMS(category, status, imgLink);

                if(i==data_array.length()-1){
                    lastId=id;
                    new SendLastID().execute();
                }

            }

            new ListAdapter(CatagoryActivity.this, objlist)
                    .notifyDataSetChanged();



        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

DatabaseHelper :- in this file code to insert parsed data in sqlite database

```
public  void addSMS(String category,String status,String imageLink) {


               SQLiteDatabase db123 = this.getWritableDatabase();

                    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
                    values.put(MessagesAdapter.CATEGORY, category);
                    values.put(MessagesAdapter.Status, status);
                    values.put(MessagesAdapter.Imagelink,imageLink);

                    db123.insert(MessagesAdapter.TBL_CATEGORY, null, values);
                    //SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("SMS",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                    //SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
                    //editor.putString("IS_ADDED_IN_DB","YES");
                    //editor.commit();
                    Log.e("TAG","JSON DATA INSERTED"+values);



                    //Toast.makeText(mContext, "Data Iserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    db123.close();
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this,

check before data adding in Database,

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences("SMS",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
if (!(sharedPreferences.getString(Constant.userId, NO).equalsIgnoreCase("YES")){
       dataBaseHelper.addSMS(category, status, imgLink);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of preventing duplicate entries in db using `SharedPreferences` , use [SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#insertWithOnConflict(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20int)) method with [SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#CONFLICT_IGNORE) constant.

**Example:**

```
db123.insertWithOnConflict(MessagesAdapter.TBL_CATEGORY, 
                           null, 
                           values, 
                           SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_IGNORE);
```

And also make `primary-key`  to `MessagesAdapter.CATEGORY` column to avoid duplicate entry in `MessagesAdapter.TBL_CATEGORY` table according to categories.